# Query to find nᵗʰ max value of a column

Tags: sql, database

How can I find the 2<sup>nd</sup>, 3<sup>rd</sup>, ... n<sup>th</sup> maximum value of a column?

Comment: What database? I don't think there is a very good "generic" solution to this problem.

Comment: too generic I think: specify at least on which DBMS...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could sort the column into descending format and then just obtain the value from the nth row.

EDIT::

Updated as per comment request. ***WARNING*** completely untested!

```
SELECT DOB FROM (SELECT DOB FROM USERS ORDER BY DOB DESC) WHERE ROWID = 6
```

Something like the above should work for Oracle ... you might have to get the syntax right first!

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet? I tried your suggestion but I was unable to obtain value from the nth row.

Comment: Using `ROWID` is neither a safe nor a practical  thing to do. Take the case of [tag:sqlite]. `ROWID` may or may not be generated serially. Moreover the order of `ROWID` might not match with that of the requested column.

Comment: This will be slow as it requires ordering the whole table first before then selecting the nth row. Some databases now provide this functionality see answers below from Pieter and Steven Dickinson, for example.

Answer (score 43):

Consider the following Employee table with a single column for salary.

```
+------+
| Sal  |
+------+
| 3500 | 
| 2500 | 
| 2500 | 
| 5500 |
| 7500 |
+------+
```

The following query will return the Nth Maximum element.

```
select SAL from EMPLOYEE E1 where 
 (N - 1) = (select count(distinct(SAL)) 
            from EMPLOYEE E2 
            where E2.SAL > E1.SAL )
```

For eg. when the second maximum value is required,

```
  select SAL from EMPLOYEE E1 where 
     (2 - 1) = (select count(distinct(SAL)) 
                from EMPLOYEE E2 
                where E2.SAL > E1.SAL )
```

```
+------+
| Sal  |
+------+
| 5500 |
+------+
```

Comment: An easy solution bound to work on all databases! Nice thinking! :)

Comment: Great answer! I have faced this problem before and was troubled about how to solve it without being specific to a vendor :) One possible drawback is that it does a subquery for each row.

Comment: This is awesome! I am using it with `>=` operator to get all the rows with up to Nth position. I would like to add a ranking to it, like '1' for the max value, '2' for the second max, etc.. Do you have any idea how to go about it.

Comment: @NurShomik if you need a generic function for rank, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3333697/1385252

Comment: please explain. I am not being able to understand, how Comparison is helping us out.

Comment: it was great , but would be better if you could please provide an explanation how it executes

Comment: How do you deal with subquery returns more than 1 row for N = 4?

Comment: Modifying it to `Select DISTINCT SAL from EMPLOYEE E1 where` .... worked

Comment: way more sophisticated and versatile than other answers. 
Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a58ad/7

Comment: Please note that this query is very expensive in large tables, as it scans all the rows.

Answer (score 15):

You didn't specify which database, on MySQL you can do

```
SELECT column FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 7,10;
```

Would skip the first 7, and then get you the next ten highest.

Comment: If you are using mysql, this wont work in oracle (or mssql I believe)

Answer (score 9):

Again you may need to fix for your database, but if you want the top 2nd value in a dataset that potentially has the value duplicated, you'll want to do a group as well:

```
SELECT column 
FROM table 
WHERE column IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY column 
ORDER BY column DESC 
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 2;
```

Would skip the first two, and then will get you the next five highest.

Answer (score 5):

Pure SQL (note: I would recommend using SQL features specific to your DBMS since it will be likely more efficient). This will get you the n+1th largest value (to get smallest, flip the <). If you have duplicates, make it COUNT( DISTINCT VALUE )..

```
select id from table order by id desc limit 4 ;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 2211 | 
| 2210 | 
| 2209 | 
| 2208 | 
+------+


SELECT yourvalue
  FROM yourtable t1
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT COUNT(*)
                 FROM yourtable t2
                WHERE t1.id       <> t2.id
                  AND t1.yourvalue < t2.yourvalue
               HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 )


+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 2208 | 
+------+
```

Answer (score 3):

(Table Name=Student, Column Name= mark)

```
select * from(select row_number() over (order by mark desc) as t,mark from student group by mark) as td where t=4
```

Comment: MS SQL Server [row_number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the nth largest value of column by using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName a WHERE
    n = (SELECT count(DISTINCT(b.ColumnName)) 
    FROM TableName b WHERE a.ColumnName <=b.ColumnName);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select column_name from table_name 
order by column_name desc limit n-1,1;
```

where n = 1, 2, 3,....nth max value.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method for Oracle.  This example gets the 9th highest value.  Simply replace the 9 with a bind variable containing the position you are looking for.

```
   select created from (
     select created from (
       select created from user_objects
         order by created desc
       )
       where rownum <= 9
       order by created asc
     )
     where rownum = 1
```

If you wanted the nth unique value, you would add DISTINCT on the innermost query block.

Answer (score 1):

Just dug out this question when looking for the answer myself, and this seems to work for SQL Server 2005 (derived from [Blorgbeard's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80706/query-to-find-nth-max-value-of-a-column/80771#80771)):

```
SELECT MIN(q.col1) FROM (
    SELECT
        DISTINCT TOP n col1
        FROM myTable
        ORDER BY col1 DESC
) q;
```

Effectively, that is a `SELECT MIN(q.someCol) FROM someTable q`, with the top n of the table retrieved by the `SELECT DISTINCT...` query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select max(sal) 
from table t1 
where N (select max(sal) 
        from table t2 
        where t2.sal > t1.sal)
```

To find the Nth max sal.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE columnname<(select max(columnname) from tablename) 
order by columnname desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is query for getting  nth Highest from colomn put n=0 for second highest and n= 1 for 3rd highest and so on...

```
 SELECT * FROM TableName
 WHERE ColomnName<(select max(ColomnName) from TableName)-n order by ColomnName desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple SQL Query to get the employee detail who has Nth MAX `Salary` in the table `Employee`.**

```
sql> select * from Employee order by salary desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET <N - 1>;
```

*Consider table structure as:*

> Employee ( 
>         id [int primary key auto_increment], 
>         name [varchar(30)], 
>         salary [int] );

**Example:**

If you need 3rd `MAX` salary in the above table then, query will be:

```
sql> select * from Employee order by salary desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

**Similarly:**

If you need 8th `MAX` salary in the above table then, query will be:

```
sql> select * from Employee order by salary desc LIMIT 1 OFFSET 7;
```

> **NOTE:**
>   When you have to get the *Nth* `MAX` value you should give the `OFFSET` as *(N - 1)*.

*Like this you can do same kind of operation in case of salary in ascending order.*

Answer (score 1):

**mysql query**:
*suppose i want to find out nth max salary form employee table*

```
select salary 
form employee
order by salary desc
limit n-1,1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, just do:

```
select distinct top n+1 column from table order by column desc
```

And then throw away the first value, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

for SQL 2005:

```
SELECT col1 from 
     (select col1, dense_rank(col1) over (order by col1 desc) ranking 
     from t1) subq where ranking between 2 and @n
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one for Oracle using analytic functions:

```
select distinct col1 --distinct is required to remove matching value of column
from 
( select col1, dense_rank() over (order by col1 desc) rnk
  from tbl
)
where rnk = :b1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sal,ename from emp e where
 2=(select count(distinct sal) from emp  where e.sal<=emp.sal) or
 3=(select count(distinct sal) from emp  where e.sal<=emp.sal) or
 4=(select count(distinct sal) from emp  where e.sal<=emp.sal) order by sal desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
select distinct(salary) from employee order by salary desc limit (n-1), 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer :
top second:

```
select * from (select * from deletetable   where rownum <=2 order by rownum desc) where rownum <=1
```

Comment: When you don't add something new, please don't answer 4 year old questions :)

Answer (score 0):

(TableName=Student, ColumnName=Mark) :

```
select *
from student 
where mark=(select mark 
            from(select row_number() over (order by mark desc) as t,
                 mark 
                 from student group by mark) as td 
            where t=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the query below will work just perfect on oracle sql...I have tested it myself..

Info related to this query : this query is using two tables named `employee` and `department` with columns in employee named: `name` (employee name), `dept_id` (common to employee and department), `salary`

And columns in department table: `dept_id` (common for employee table as well), `dept_name`

```
SELECT
  tab.dept_name,MIN(tab.salary) AS Second_Max_Sal FROM (
    SELECT e.name, e.salary, d.dept_name, dense_rank() over (partition BY  d.dept_name          ORDER BY e.salary)  AS   rank FROM department d JOIN employee e USING (dept_id) )  tab
 WHERE
   rank  BETWEEN 1 AND 2
 GROUP BY
   tab.dept_name
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select min(fee) 
from fl_FLFee 
where fee in (Select top 4 Fee from fl_FLFee order by 1 desc)
```

Change Number four with N.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify like this

```
SELECT MIN(Sal) FROM TableName
WHERE Sal IN
(SELECT TOP 4 Sal FROM TableName ORDER BY Sal DESC)
```

If the Sal contains duplicate values then use this

```
SELECT MIN(Sal) FROM TableName
WHERE Sal IN
(SELECT distinct TOP 4 Sal FROM TableName ORDER BY Sal DESC)
```

the 4 will be nth value it may any highest value such as 5 or 6 etc.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, to find N-th largest salary from Employee table.

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE salary in 
(SELECT salary FROM Employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT N) 
ORDER BY salary ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to find Nth Maximum value of a particular column in SQL Server:

Employee table:

[image: Employee Table]

Sales table:

[image: Sales Table]

Employee table data:

```
==========
Id  name
=========
6   ARSHAD M
7   Manu
8   Shaji
```

Sales table data:

```
=================
id  emp_id   amount
=================
1   6        500
2   7        100
3   8        100
4   6        150
5   7        130
6   7        130
7   7        330
```

Query to Find out details of an employee who have highest sale/ **N**th highest salesperson

```
select * from (select E.Id,E.name,SUM(S.amount) AS 'total_amount' from employee E INNER JOIN Sale S on E.Id=S.emp_id group by S.emp_id,E.Id,E.name ) AS T1 WHERE(0)=( select COUNT(DISTINCT(total_amount)) from(select E.Id,E.name,SUM(S.amount) AS 'total_amount' from employee E INNER JOIN Sale S on E.Id=S.emp_id group by S.emp_id,E.Id,E.name )AS T2 WHERE(T1.total_amount<T2.total_amount) );
```

In the **WHERE(0)** replace 0 by n-1

Result:

```
========================
id  name    total_amount
========================
7   Manu    690
```

Answer (score -1):

Table employee

```
salary 
1256
1256
2563
8546
5645
```

You find the second max value by this query

```
select salary 
from employee 
where salary=(select max(salary) 
                from employee 
                where salary <(select max(salary) from employee));
```

You find the third max value by this query

```
select salary 
from employee 
where salary=(select max(salary) 
                from employee 
                where salary <(select max(salary) 
                                from employee 
                                where salary <(select max(salary)from employee)));
```

Comment: The outermost selects are extraneous. Stopping at the first max(salary) would have worked.

Comment: This solution is nuts.