# Rank function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, rank

I need to find out rank of customers. Here I am adding the corresponding ANSI standard SQL query for my requirement. Please help me to convert it to MySQL .

```
SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY Age) AS [Partition by Gender], 
  FirstName, 
  Age,
  Gender 
FROM Person
```

Is there any function to find out rank in MySQL?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

One option is to use a ranking variable, such as the following:

```
SELECT    first_name,
          age,
          gender,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM      person p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  age;
```

The `(SELECT @curRank := 0)` part allows the variable initialization without requiring a separate `SET` command.

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id int, first_name varchar(20), age int, gender char(1));

INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, 'Bob', 25, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2, 'Jane', 20, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'Jack', 30, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (4, 'Bill', 32, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (5, 'Nick', 22, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (6, 'Kathy', 18, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (7, 'Steve', 36, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (8, 'Anne', 25, 'F');
```

Result:

```
+------------+------+--------+------+
| first_name | age  | gender | rank |
+------------+------+--------+------+
| Kathy      |   18 | F      |    1 |
| Jane       |   20 | F      |    2 |
| Nick       |   22 | M      |    3 |
| Bob        |   25 | M      |    4 |
| Anne       |   25 | F      |    5 |
| Jack       |   30 | M      |    6 |
| Bill       |   32 | M      |    7 |
| Steve      |   36 | M      |    8 |
+------------+------+--------+------+
8 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: +1 for the devious inline initialization, that's a beautiful trick.

Comment: Didn't he ask for a partition though? My understanding of partitions is that the result set would have separate rankings for male and female.

Comment: @Jesse: If that is the case, I recently answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162389/multiple-ranks-in-one-table/

Comment: What if I want to give rank as 4 to Anne and Bob both?

Comment: @FahimParkar: See the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727138/update-the-rank-in-a-mysql-table/2727239#2727239 - Go down to the part that says "UPDATE:" You probably don't want to have an UPDATE statement, but you can probably get the logic from the inner SELECT.

Comment: This does not implement the example from the question as it misses the `partition by gender` part of the analytical function (which "numbers" the rank value *per gender* not for the overall result)

Comment: i know this is too old. But this doesnt/too slow works on very large tables

Comment: @DanielVassallo What about ties? If there were ties, this would give them different ranks. Thus, I think this is a row numbering function, not a ranking function. Correct me if I am missing something.

Comment: @DanielVassallo: its not categorizing rank based on Gender !!

Comment: As I see, for duplicate values, we are assigning different ranks. That's not the correct behavior of Rank function.

Comment: This is not not giving the rank, it is giving the row number - the rank should be the same if the values are the same

Comment: This answer is wrong. It doesn't address the PARTITION BY. Shouldn't be upvoted or accepted.

Comment: I run this query in 50k records, I got the timeout

Comment: This doesn't emulate `RANK()`, it emulates `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: I have additional doubt on top of that. This solution uses @variables which scope is the session. Is that any (even paranoiac) scenario when the query is run several times in parallel sharing the same variable and thus giving the false output?

Answer (score 60):

Here is a generic solution that assigns dense rank over partition to rows. It uses user variables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(10),
    gender VARCHAR(1),
    age INT
);

INSERT INTO person (id, firstname, gender, age) VALUES
(1,  'Adams',  'M', 33),
(2,  'Matt',   'M', 31),
(3,  'Grace',  'F', 25),
(4,  'Harry',  'M', 20),
(5,  'Scott',  'M', 30),
(6,  'Sarah',  'F', 30),
(7,  'Tony',   'M', 30),
(8,  'Lucy',   'F', 27),
(9,  'Zoe',    'F', 30),
(10, 'Megan',  'F', 26),
(11, 'Emily',  'F', 20),
(12, 'Peter',  'M', 20),
(13, 'John',   'M', 21),
(14, 'Kate',   'F', 35),
(15, 'James',  'M', 32),
(16, 'Cole',   'M', 25),
(17, 'Dennis', 'M', 27),
(18, 'Smith',  'M', 35),
(19, 'Zack',   'M', 35),
(20, 'Jill',   'F', 25);

SELECT person.*, @rank := CASE
    WHEN @partval = gender AND @rankval = age THEN @rank
    WHEN @partval = gender AND (@rankval := age) IS NOT NULL THEN @rank + 1
    WHEN (@partval := gender) IS NOT NULL AND (@rankval := age) IS NOT NULL THEN 1
END AS rnk
FROM person, (SELECT @rank := NULL, @partval := NULL, @rankval := NULL) AS x
ORDER BY gender, age;
```

Notice that the variable assignments are placed inside the `CASE` expression. This (in theory) takes care of order of evaluation issue. The `IS NOT NULL` is added to handle datatype conversion and short circuiting issues.

PS: It can easily be converted to row number over partition by by removing all conditions that check for tie.

```
| id | firstname | gender | age | rank |
|----|-----------|--------|-----|------|
| 11 | Emily     | F      | 20  | 1    |
| 20 | Jill      | F      | 25  | 2    |
| 3  | Grace     | F      | 25  | 2    |
| 10 | Megan     | F      | 26  | 3    |
| 8  | Lucy      | F      | 27  | 4    |
| 6  | Sarah     | F      | 30  | 5    |
| 9  | Zoe       | F      | 30  | 5    |
| 14 | Kate      | F      | 35  | 6    |
| 4  | Harry     | M      | 20  | 1    |
| 12 | Peter     | M      | 20  | 1    |
| 13 | John      | M      | 21  | 2    |
| 16 | Cole      | M      | 25  | 3    |
| 17 | Dennis    | M      | 27  | 4    |
| 7  | Tony      | M      | 30  | 5    |
| 5  | Scott     | M      | 30  | 5    |
| 2  | Matt      | M      | 31  | 6    |
| 15 | James     | M      | 32  | 7    |
| 1  | Adams     | M      | 33  | 8    |
| 18 | Smith     | M      | 35  | 9    |
| 19 | Zack      | M      | 35  | 9    |
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33d297088fe6b8c44b73e1b43e08902a)

Comment: This solution, or Mukesh's solution, should be the correct solution. Although technically I believe both of you guys' solutions represent a [dense ranking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) and not a regular rank. Here is a good explanation of the differences: http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2009/04/rank-vs-denserank-with-example-using.html.

Comment: Can you also let us know how is .php code exactly should be? I tried to follow, but above code does not work. How to input to .php format?

Comment: This solution is not very generic; it won't work if rank_column has a value of 0.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c5dd/1

Comment: @mike Use `@rank_count := IF(@prev_value = rank_column, @rank_count, @rank_count + 1)` instead.

Comment: @mike Add an ELSE section to the CASE statement: `ELSE @rank_count := @rank_count + 1`

Comment: @abhash `ORDER BY gender, age DESC`?

Answer (score 59):

While the most upvoted answer ranks, it doesn't partition, You can do a self Join to get the whole thing partitioned also:

```
SELECT    a.first_name,
      a.age,
      a.gender,
        count(b.age)+1 as rank
FROM  person a left join person b on a.age>b.age and a.gender=b.gender 
group by  a.first_name,
      a.age,
      a.gender
```

**Use Case**

```
CREATE TABLE person (id int, first_name varchar(20), age int, gender char(1));

INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, 'Bob', 25, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2, 'Jane', 20, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'Jack', 30, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (4, 'Bill', 32, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (5, 'Nick', 22, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (6, 'Kathy', 18, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (7, 'Steve', 36, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (8, 'Anne', 25, 'F');
```

**Answer**:

```
Bill    32  M   4
Bob     25  M   2
Jack    30  M   3
Nick    22  M   1
Steve   36  M   5
Anne    25  F   3
Jane    20  F   2
Kathy   18  F   1
```

Comment: this is a wonderful answer precisely because I need to do a partition ranking. Thank you, sir!

Comment: IMO it has same complexity as subselect in the @Sam Kidman's answer: O(n^2). But dunno know if it's possible to do it better in MySQL.

Comment: Check out http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=1 for a great tutorial along the same lines

Comment: Self-join to get the rank! That's great. At last, a solution _without variables_ and _without MySQL 8 window functions_. :)

Answer (score 25):

A tweak of Daniel's version to calculate percentile along with rank. Also two people with same marks will get the same rank.

```
set @totalStudents = 0;
select count(*) into @totalStudents from marksheets;
SELECT id, score, @curRank := IF(@prevVal=score, @curRank, @studentNumber) AS rank, 
@percentile := IF(@prevVal=score, @percentile, (@totalStudents - @studentNumber + 1)/(@totalStudents)*100),
@studentNumber := @studentNumber + 1 as studentNumber, 
@prevVal:=score
FROM marksheets, (
SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevVal:=null, @studentNumber:=1, @percentile:=100
) r
ORDER BY score DESC
```

Results of the query for a sample data -

```
+----+-------+------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| id | score | rank | percentile    | studentNumber | @prevVal:=score |
+----+-------+------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
| 10 |    98 |    1 | 100.000000000 |             2 |              98 |
|  5 |    95 |    2 |  90.000000000 |             3 |              95 |
|  6 |    91 |    3 |  80.000000000 |             4 |              91 |
|  2 |    91 |    3 |  80.000000000 |             5 |              91 |
|  8 |    90 |    5 |  60.000000000 |             6 |              90 |
|  1 |    90 |    5 |  60.000000000 |             7 |              90 |
|  9 |    84 |    7 |  40.000000000 |             8 |              84 |
|  3 |    83 |    8 |  30.000000000 |             9 |              83 |
|  4 |    72 |    9 |  20.000000000 |            10 |              72 |
|  7 |    60 |   10 |  10.000000000 |            11 |              60 |
+----+-------+------+---------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Even though this isn't really optimal in performance, it's awesome!

Answer (score 20):

Combination of Daniel's and Salman's answer. However the rank will not give as continues sequence with ties exists . Instead it skips the rank to next. So maximum always reach row count.

```
    SELECT    first_name,
              age,
              gender,
              IF(age=@_last_age,@curRank:=@curRank,@curRank:=@_sequence) AS rank,
              @_sequence:=@_sequence+1,@_last_age:=age
    FROM      person p, (SELECT @curRank := 1, @_sequence:=1, @_last_age:=0) r
    ORDER BY  age;
```

Schema and Test Case:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id int, first_name varchar(20), age int, gender char(1));

INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, 'Bob', 25, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2, 'Jane', 20, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'Jack', 30, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (4, 'Bill', 32, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (5, 'Nick', 22, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (6, 'Kathy', 18, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (7, 'Steve', 36, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (8, 'Anne', 25, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (9, 'Kamal', 25, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (10, 'Saman', 32, 'M');
```

Output:

```
+------------+------+--------+------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| first_name | age  | gender | rank | @_sequence:=@_sequence+1 | @_last_age:=age |
+------------+------+--------+------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Kathy      |   18 | F      |    1 |                        2 |              18 |
| Jane       |   20 | F      |    2 |                        3 |              20 |
| Nick       |   22 | M      |    3 |                        4 |              22 |
| Kamal      |   25 | M      |    4 |                        5 |              25 |
| Anne       |   25 | F      |    4 |                        6 |              25 |
| Bob        |   25 | M      |    4 |                        7 |              25 |
| Jack       |   30 | M      |    7 |                        8 |              30 |
| Bill       |   32 | M      |    8 |                        9 |              32 |
| Saman      |   32 | M      |    8 |                       10 |              32 |
| Steve      |   36 | M      |   10 |                       11 |              36 |
+------------+------+--------+------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I am new to MySQL but is this solution ok? In MySQL docs says "the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html

Answer (score 20):

#### MySQL 5.7

In MySQL 5.7, you can use JSON and local variables as follows, to emulate `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ..)`:

```sql
SELECT
  FirstName, Age, Gender,
  coalesce(
    json_extract(
      @rn := json_set(@rn, 
        @rnpath := concat('$."rn-', Gender, '"'), 
        @currn := coalesce(json_extract(@rn, @rnpath), 0) + 1,
        @prevpath := concat('$."pre-v-', Gender, '"'),
        Age,
        @prernpath := concat('$."pre-rn-', Gender, '"'),
        IF (json_extract(@rn, @prevpath) = Age, 
          coalesce(json_extract(@rn, @prernpath), @currn) div 1,
          @currn
        )
      ), 
      @prernpath
    ), 
    @currn
  ) AS rn2
FROM Person, (SELECT @rn := '{}') r
ORDER BY Age DESC;
```

Per partition key, this stores the `ROW_NUMBER()` (`"rn-x"`), previous value according to the sort key (`"pre-v-x"`), as well as the previous `ROW_NUMBER()` (`"pre-rn-x"`) for tied rows, to emulate `RANK()` behaviour. The benefit of using JSON here is that the `PARTITION BY` clause does not influence the ordering of the query.

#### MySQL 8.0

Starting with MySQL 8, you can finally use window functions also in MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html

Your query can be written exactly the same way:

```sql
SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY Age) AS `Partition by Gender`, 
  FirstName, 
  Age,
  Gender 
FROM Person
```

Comment: It is not wrong just does not work with older versions of SQL. plus it was kinda of copy and past of his question so it does not feel like it fits the answer.

Comment: @brand-it For those of on MySQL 8+, this answer is important since it lets us know that Rank is now available.  If I hadn't scrolled down this far, I'd assume the earlier answers were the only solution.

Comment: @SteveSmith Good point it is nice to have this answer for those use the newer version of MYSQL.

Comment: Yes, I am discouraged by a lot of answers with the user variables and logic blocks. A new versions of MySQL allows do it MUCH simple with RANK() function that offers a built in grouping by partitions.

Answer (score 6):

@Sam, your point is excellent in concept but I think you misunderstood what the MySQL docs are saying on the referenced page -- or I misunderstand :-) -- and I just wanted to add this so that if someone feels uncomfortable with the @Daniel's answer they'll be more reassured or at least dig a little deeper.

You see the `"@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank"` inside the `SELECT` is not "one statement", it's one "atomic" part of the statement so it should be safe.

The document you reference goes on to show examples where the same user-defined variable in 2 (atomic) parts of the statement, for example, `"SELECT @curRank, @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank"`.

One might argue that `@curRank` is used twice in @Daniel's answer: (1) the `"@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank"` and (2) the `"(SELECT @curRank := 0) r"` but since the second usage is part of the `FROM` clause, I'm pretty sure it is guaranteed to be evaluated first; essentially making it a second, and preceding, statement.

In fact, on that same MySQL docs page you referenced, you'll see the same solution in the comments -- it could be where @Daniel got it from; yeah, I know that it's the comments but it is comments on the official docs page and that does carry some weight.

Comment: None of this is justfied by the documentation. It is just (fuzzy) speculation. As are all the answers both using & writing the same variable, which the manual says is explicitly not defined, although the manual does have a lot of unhelpful text re what might work as you expect, without saying what it thinks you expect or what use a description of non-guaranteed behaviour is. PS As of 8.0 variable assignment outside SET is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

The most straight forward solution to determine the rank of a given value is to count the number of values *before* it. Suppose we have the following values:

```
10 20 30 30 30 40
```

- All `30` values are considered **3rd**
- All `40` values are considered **6th** (rank) or **4th** (dense rank)

---

Now back to the original question. Here is some sample data which is sorted as described in OP (expected ranks are added on the right):

```
+------+-----------+------+--------+    +------+------------+
| id   | firstname | age  | gender |    | rank | dense_rank |
+------+-----------+------+--------+    +------+------------+
|   11 | Emily     |   20 | F      |    |    1 |          1 |
|    3 | Grace     |   25 | F      |    |    2 |          2 |
|   20 | Jill      |   25 | F      |    |    2 |          2 |
|   10 | Megan     |   26 | F      |    |    4 |          3 |
|    8 | Lucy      |   27 | F      |    |    5 |          4 |
|    6 | Sarah     |   30 | F      |    |    6 |          5 |
|    9 | Zoe       |   30 | F      |    |    6 |          5 |
|   14 | Kate      |   35 | F      |    |    8 |          6 |
|    4 | Harry     |   20 | M      |    |    1 |          1 |
|   12 | Peter     |   20 | M      |    |    1 |          1 |
|   13 | John      |   21 | M      |    |    3 |          2 |
|   16 | Cole      |   25 | M      |    |    4 |          3 |
|   17 | Dennis    |   27 | M      |    |    5 |          4 |
|    5 | Scott     |   30 | M      |    |    6 |          5 |
|    7 | Tony      |   30 | M      |    |    6 |          5 |
|    2 | Matt      |   31 | M      |    |    8 |          6 |
|   15 | James     |   32 | M      |    |    9 |          7 |
|    1 | Adams     |   33 | M      |    |   10 |          8 |
|   18 | Smith     |   35 | M      |    |   11 |          9 |
|   19 | Zack      |   35 | M      |    |   11 |          9 |
+------+-----------+------+--------+    +------+------------+
```

To calculate `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY Age)` for ***Sarah***, you can use this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) + 1 AS rank, COUNT(DISTINCT age) + 1 AS dense_rank
FROM testdata
WHERE gender = (SELECT gender FROM testdata WHERE id = 6)
AND age < (SELECT age FROM testdata WHERE id = 6)

+------+------------+
| rank | dense_rank |
+------+------------+
|    6 |          5 |
+------+------------+
```

To calculate `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY Age)` for ***All*** rows you can use this query:

```
SELECT testdata.id, COUNT(lesser.id) + 1 AS rank, COUNT(DISTINCT lesser.age) + 1 AS dense_rank
FROM testdata
LEFT JOIN testdata AS lesser ON lesser.age < testdata.age AND lesser.gender = testdata.gender
GROUP BY testdata.id
```

And here is the result (joined values are added on right):

```
+------+------+------------+    +-----------+-----+--------+
| id   | rank | dense_rank |    | firstname | age | gender |
+------+------+------------+    +-----------+-----+--------+
|   11 |    1 |          1 |    | Emily     |  20 | F      |
|    3 |    2 |          2 |    | Grace     |  25 | F      |
|   20 |    2 |          2 |    | Jill      |  25 | F      |
|   10 |    4 |          3 |    | Megan     |  26 | F      |
|    8 |    5 |          4 |    | Lucy      |  27 | F      |
|    6 |    6 |          5 |    | Sarah     |  30 | F      |
|    9 |    6 |          5 |    | Zoe       |  30 | F      |
|   14 |    8 |          6 |    | Kate      |  35 | F      |
|    4 |    1 |          1 |    | Harry     |  20 | M      |
|   12 |    1 |          1 |    | Peter     |  20 | M      |
|   13 |    3 |          2 |    | John      |  21 | M      |
|   16 |    4 |          3 |    | Cole      |  25 | M      |
|   17 |    5 |          4 |    | Dennis    |  27 | M      |
|    5 |    6 |          5 |    | Scott     |  30 | M      |
|    7 |    6 |          5 |    | Tony      |  30 | M      |
|    2 |    8 |          6 |    | Matt      |  31 | M      |
|   15 |    9 |          7 |    | James     |  32 | M      |
|    1 |   10 |          8 |    | Adams     |  33 | M      |
|   18 |   11 |          9 |    | Smith     |  35 | M      |
|   19 |   11 |          9 |    | Zack      |  35 | M      |
+------+------+------------+    +-----------+-----+--------+
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rank just one person you can do the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(Age) + 1
 FROM PERSON
WHERE(Age < age_to_rank)
```

This ranking corresponds to the oracle RANK function  (Where if you have people with the same age they get the same rank, and the ranking after that is non-consecutive).

It's a little bit faster than using one of the above solutions in a subquery and selecting from that to get the ranking of one person.

This can be used to rank everyone but it's slower than the above solutions.

```
SELECT
  Age AS age_var,
(
  SELECT COUNT(Age) + 1
  FROM Person
  WHERE (Age < age_var)
 ) AS rank
 FROM Person
```

Comment: It may become **much** slower than above solutions when the number of rows in the `Person` table grows. It's _O(n^2)_ vs _O(n)_ slower.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the "[however](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25550039/4985705)" in Erandac's answer in combination of Daniel's and Salman's answers, one may use one of the following "partition workarounds"

```
SELECT customerID, myDate

  -- partition ranking works only with CTE / from MySQL 8.0 on
  , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY customerID ORDER BY dateFrom) AS rank, 

  -- Erandac's method in combination of Daniel's and Salman's
  -- count all items in sequence, maximum reaches row count.
  , IF(customerID=@_lastRank, @_curRank:=@_curRank, @_curRank:=@_sequence+1) AS sequenceRank
  , @_sequence:=@_sequence+1 as sequenceOverAll

  -- Dense partition ranking, works also with MySQL 5.7
  -- remember to set offset values in from clause
  , IF(customerID=@_lastRank, @_nxtRank:=@_nxtRank, @_nxtRank:=@_nxtRank+1 ) AS partitionRank
  , IF(customerID=@_lastRank, @_overPart:=@_overPart+1, @_overPart:=1 ) AS partitionSequence

  , @_lastRank:=customerID
FROM myCustomers, 
  (SELECT @_curRank:=0, @_sequence:=0, @_lastRank:=0, @_nxtRank:=0, @_overPart:=0 ) r
ORDER BY customerID, myDate
```

The partition ranking in the 3rd variant in this code snippet will return continous ranking numbers. this will lead to a data structur similar to the `rank() over partition by` result. As an example, see below. In particular, **the partitionSequence will always start with 1 for each new partitionRank**, using this method:

```
customerID    myDate   sequenceRank (Erandac)
                          |    sequenceOverAll
                          |     |   partitionRank
                          |     |     | partitionSequence
                          |     |     |    | lastRank
... lines ommitted for clarity
40    09.11.2016 11:19    1     44    1   44    40
40    09.12.2016 12:08    1     45    1   45    40
40    09.12.2016 12:08    1     46    1   46    40
40    09.12.2016 12:11    1     47    1   47    40
40    09.12.2016 12:12    1     48    1   48    40
40    13.10.2017 16:31    1     49    1   49    40
40    15.10.2017 11:00    1     50    1   50    40
76    01.07.2015 00:24    51    51    2    1    76
77    04.08.2014 13:35    52    52    3    1    77
79    15.04.2015 20:25    53    53    4    1    79
79    24.04.2018 11:44    53    54    4    2    79
79    08.10.2018 17:37    53    55    4    3    79
117   09.07.2014 18:21    56    56    5    1   117
119   26.06.2014 13:55    57    57    6    1   119
119   02.03.2015 10:23    57    58    6    2   119
119   12.10.2015 10:16    57    59    6    3   119
119   08.04.2016 09:32    57    60    6    4   119
119   05.10.2016 12:41    57    61    6    5   119
119   05.10.2016 12:42    57    62    6    6   119
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id,first_name,gender,age,
rank() over(partition by gender order by age) rank_g
from person

CREATE TABLE person (id int, first_name varchar(20), age int, gender char(1));

INSERT INTO person VALUES (1, 'Bob', 25, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (2, 'Jane', 20, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (3, 'Jack', 30, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (4, 'Bill', 32, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (5, 'Nick', 22, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (6, 'Kathy', 18, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (7, 'Steve', 36, 'M');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (8, 'Anne', 25, 'F');
INSERT INTO person VALUES (9,'AKSH',32,'M');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName,Age,Gender, RANK() OVER (partition by Gender order by Age desc) AS 'Partition by Gender' FROM Person
```

- you can use asc/desc depending on which order you want if whether ascending or descending

Answer (score 0):

In a tweak to Daniel's answer,
Some MySQL Versions throw errors at the IF statement

```
SELECT    first_name,
          age,
          gender,
          (IF(age=@_last_age,@curRank:=@curRank,@curRank:=@_sequence)) AS `rank`,
          @_sequence:=@_sequence+1,@_last_age:=age
FROM      person p, (SELECT @curRank := 1, @_sequence:=1, @_last_age:=0) r
ORDER BY  age;
```

So I had to wrap  the IF condition testing in Ranking with braces

This anly calculates ranking but not Dense_rank

Answer (score 0):

```
set @insert_rank = -2;

SELECT c_updated_time,
@insert_rank := IF(true = true, @insert_rank + 1, 1) 
from my_table limit 5;
```

---

This line will print the select above query;

```
select @v_query1;
```

---

```
show variables like '%read_only%';
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'USERNAME'@'localhost';
```

1660616f-f908-4d7e-ab60-c00b77adaf96

```
select count(*) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
SHOW DATABASES WHERE `Database` IN ('information_schema', 'mysql', 'performance_schema');
use INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
show tables;
desc INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%columnname%' and TABLE_SCHEMA like '%Database%' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME;
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TableName' and TABLE_SCHEMA <> 'test' ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ,COLUMN_NAME;
```

For Date column

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE() AS current_date;
```

For timestamp column

```
select now();
```