# How to find the nth largest salary by department using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, window-functions, correlated-subquery

Say all the employees are listed in the same table `employees` along with their departments. How would you find the nth largest salary by department?

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80706/query-to-find-n%E1%B5%97%CA%B0-max-value-of-a-column) gets you pretty close.

```
select SAL from EMPLOYEE E1 where 
 (N - 1) = (select count(distinct(SAL)) 
            from EMPLOYEE E2 
            where E2.SAL > E1.SAL )
```

But adding groupby still wouldn't get you there unless you did a join on the condition?

```
select SAL from EMPLOYEE E1

where 
 (N - 1) = (select count(distinct(SAL)) 
            from EMPLOYEE E2 
            inner join EMPLOYEE E3 ON department_id
            where E2.SAL > E3.SAL )
groupby department
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is homework and you have to use a correlated subquery then you must correlate also the `department`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.department, e1.SAL 
FROM EMPLOYEE e1 
WHERE (N - 1) = (
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT e2.SAL) 
  FROM EMPLOYEE e2 
  WHERE e2.department = e1.department AND e2.SAL > e1.SAL 
);
```

A better solution would be to use `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT department, SAL
FROM ( 
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY department ORDER BY SAL DESC) dr
  FROM EMPLOYEE 
)
WHERE dr = N;
```

Comment: Not homework, just learning some SQL, thanks!